# Word cloud of keywords in Python

Tags: python, word-cloud

I'm using Python to create a word cloud of keywords in a journal. The problem I have is that I don't want separate words in the keyword to be split but instead be considered together. I managed to do this by replacing a space character `' '` by `'_'`, but now the problem is that the final image I get of course has the underscore character. This is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from os import path
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS, ImageColorGenerator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load in the dataframe
df = pd.read_csv("input/cmame_0.csv")
l = df['Author Keywords'].str.split(';', expand=False).tolist()
text = ';'.join([item for sublist in l if isinstance(sublist,list) for item in sublist])

text = text.replace(" ", "_")

stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)

# Create and generate a word cloud image:
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords,
                      max_font_size=50,
                      max_words=100,
                      background_color="white").generate(text)

# Display the generated image:
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

which produces

[image]

There's a regex expression I could use here but I can't seem to find the right regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

May be a late answer.

you can take advantage of `generate_from_frequencies` method.

**Code snippet:**

```
from collections import Counter
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

words = ["hey", "hello world", "may be", "exploring world", "something fishy"]
word_cloud_lst = Counter(words)
wordcloud = WordCloud(max_font_size=50, max_words=100, background_color="white").generate_from_frequencies(word_cloud_lst)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Here the result.

[image: wordcloud]

Answer (score -4):

```
text = text.replace(" ", "")
```

may work

Comment: How will this replace underscores with whitespace?

Comment: text = text.replace("_", "")